# remove approval option in liferay

Tags: java, content-management-system, liferay

Hi i am new to liferay cms.. when I create a content it says status pending and everytime i need to go to control panel and approve the content by entering comment twice .. Is there any option to make the content published without need to go for approval?

Comment: what version of Liferay, and what do you mean by content and where are you adding it?

Comment: I am using liferay 6.0.3 .. I added web content through add web content display and added a web content it says status not approved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to configure the workflow. Right now, you have enabled the "Single Approver" workflow process for web content. If you go to the control panel, you have a section called "Workflow Configuration" which allows you to select the workflow process you want for each type of content.

Comment: thanks for the reply... ya If I go to workflow configuration .. for web content I have 2 options in my dropdown 1.Default single approver  2.single Approver(version 1).. I dont have No workflow option for web content... how can i enable that

Answer (score 0):

First you need to configure workflow portlet:

Control panel --> Workflow configuration --> here enable the single approval option.